# SQL SELECT tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table' AND table_schema='PPcontent';";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<option value=\"", $result[0], "\">", $result[0], "</option>";}
```

I am trying to get a handle on mysqli objects and how they work. I have the above query that I am using to find the table names of a database and insert them into a select dropdown. When I used similar code to populate another select dropdown I used `$result['some_row_name']` to fetch the results when the while loop runs. Then my select statement was `SELECT 'some_row_name from 'some_table'`   When I do it with the select statement above I need to use the index 0 instead of "Table_name". Why is that? When I run the select statement above in PHP MyAdmin I get a table back with the row name 'Table_name' so I would think I would use that as an index instead of 0.

Comment: note that in your projection you have `table_name` so in the result array what you will get is `table_name` and not `Table_name` as you seem to have expected.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that and check capitalization. Is it because you are projecting a new table and creating the row name with the query "Select table_name from information_schema . . . " so in essence I could make table_name "foo" or "bar" if I wanted?

Comment: I can't remember if that's how I did it or if I changed it up. I know i got it to do what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql is generally case insensitive with column names so if the column is called MYCOLUMN you could effectively query as follows in the mysql console or with php

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable;
SELECT MYCOLUMN from mytable;
SELECT myColumn from mytable;
```

however when you use php's mysqli_fetch_array, you will have to access the column data using the exact capitalization that you used in the query here. That is because PHP is case sensitive when it comes to variable names. With languages that are not case sensitive it would not matter.

If you wanted the column to have a completely different name you can use an alias

```
SELECT mycolumn AS some_other_name FROM mytable;
```